# Not able to access picture files in android-Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-file

I want to access the picture files in public folder in external storage. Here is my code:

```
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
          java.io.File pictureDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
          ///storage/sdcard0/Pictures
          boolean canRead = pictureDir.canRead();
          //Above gives false
          java.io.File[] picFiles = pictureDir.listFiles();
          //null is returned for the file though I've atleast three picture files at this location
      }
```

It gives me correct pointer to public folder, but canRead() method returns false. When I try listing the files under Picture directory, it gives me null.

Let me know if you need more details.

**[UPDATE]**

Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**[UPDATE 2]**
This looks like a device specific issue since it works fine on emulator.

Comment: do you have needed permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes, I've android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE in android manifest. updated the question above.

Comment: try using getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES) instead of getExternalStoragePublicDirectory

Comment: getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) returns null :(

Comment: I can confirm that it is device specific. I just tried your code and it works fine on my Galaxy Nexus. Could be that your devices does not have a difference between External and Internal Memory.

Comment: Where did you find such "WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" permission? There isn't such permission. Check the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: ah...my bad...somehow i was kept reading internal as external...thanks for pointing this out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare wrong permission in you AndroidManifest.xml. You are actually using external storage. From API 16 there is new permission that is required if you are using external storage:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

> You can test your app with the permission enforced by either running
>   your app on the Android Emulator when running Android 4.1 or higher,
>   or enabling Protect USB storage under Developer options in the
>   Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

Probably in your device is set Protect USB storage in such case you need to use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. By the way `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will cover `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just chiming in with another point of "device specific" troubles..  I have a ZTE Valet that I'm trying to get access to an external directory for reading, but having the same problem where the following permission results in getExternalFilesDir() to return null:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"
    />
```

The trick mentioned above (use the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission) indeed results in a File being returned by getExternalFilesDir()...  odd.. so odd...